# Removing old markers and Polylines before adding new ones - Mapbox

Tags: javascript, maps, mapbox

Given the following code for Mapbox, whereby I am plotting points and polylines between a number of points. User will choose a different selection and the results of that will replace the pins on the map. These pins will then be drawn together in the correct order using polylines.

```
$.post('_posts/get-pins.php', {traveller: $(this).val()}, function(data){

var featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);

var featureCollection = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": []
};

var lineArray = [];

$.each(data, function (k, item) {
    featureCollection.features.push({
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "id": item.id,
            "title": item.title,
            "description": item.description,
            "image": item.image,
            "marker-symbol": "star",
            "marker-color": "#ff8888",
            "marker-size": "large"
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                item.long,
                item.lat
            ]
        }
    });

    lineArray[item.id] = [item.lat, item.long];
});

featureLayer.setGeoJSON(featureCollection);

lineArray = lineArray.filter(function(){return true});


var polyline = L.polyline(lineArray).addTo(map);

},'json');
```

So I need to remove the polylines and the markers before plotting the new ones. I have tried numerous combinations of map.removeLayer(xxx) replacing xxx with many of the variables that are being created but all I have managed to do is remove the markers. It just  leaves the polylines intact and just stacks the polyline layers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare your variables for the featureLayer and polyline outside of the method/function you are using to update them:

```
var featureLayer, polyline;
```

In the function, check if the variable featureLayer already is an instance of FeatureLayer then clear it's layers, if it's not create the new layer:

```
if (featureLayer instanceof L.mapbox.FeatureLayer) {
    featureLayer.clearLayers();
} else {
    featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);
}
```

With the polyline you got to do it differently because it hasn't got a function to clear al the added points, just check if it's an instance of L.Polyline, if so remove it from the map using L.Map's removeLayer method and afterwards just define a new polyline:

```
if (polyline instanceof L.Polyline) {
    map.removeLayer(polyline);
}

polyline = L.polyline([]).addTo(map);
```

Working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/7nlgiA50NuPGsQOF0Fv4?p=preview